# Content type to Drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, nodes

I currently have a Drupal site with a content type of Training where a variety of different training courses are listed. We are looking to sell these courses with Drupal commerce.

How do we go about turning these courses to items visitors can buy?

EDIT:

OK. I think I may have it now. Sorry for the poor comment, it was late and I hadn't messed around with commence much - Now I have!

My query is how and where best to have the fields, which I believe is a common Commerce question

Each Training has the fields of:
- Title
- Body
- Who should attend this course
- Course Structure
- Dates

How is best to sort the content fields for a Training course:

1)
Product Variation type to have all the fields above - So each course will essential be a product variation?

OR

2)
Content type to have the fields with only reference to product for the price?

My reasoning for this question is I don't have the experience to know what is best for future development where I might be looking at managing available places (Which I fore see done with stock?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend making a sandbox install of Commerce Kickstart to see how they set up "Product display node" and "Product entities" to work together. Your "Training" content type would be the Product display node, and each course offering would be the product. To replicate this on your existing site, the high-level approach (you will need to sort details) is this:

- Install Commerce and create references from Commerce `product` entities to your `Training` content type
- Create some `products` that represent your courses. You can add custom fields where needed.
- Display the `products` that are referenced to the Training nodes using Views module or methods similar to those used in Commerce Kickstart
- This should give you a list of courses on each Training node that can be added to Commerce cart.

Comment: So I have lots of different nodes for the <code>training</code> Type:
Health and Saftey
First Aid etc. etc.

I get the part about References from Commerce <code>product entities to </code>training</code> content type.

Do I also need to create <code>products</code> for each of these courses as well?

Comment: So I have lots of different nodes for the training Type:
Health and Saftey
First Aid etc. etc.

I get the part about References from Commerce product entities to training content type.

Do I also need to create products for each of these courses as well?